# Switcheroo gone after last update

Tags: 13.04, updates, vgaswitcheroo

since the last kernel update for Ubuntu 13.04, the folder `/sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch` is gone on my Laptop, an Acer Aspire 3820TG.

Checking the output of `grep -i /boot/config-*` tells me that my kernel supports switcheroo however, the file is gone (and yes, I checked that as root).

Can anybody please give me a hint? I almost checked the whole internet for an appropriate answer but nobody seems to have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and I also looked everywhere, tried everything.

Finally I got it working installing the next packages:

```
i965-va-driver intel-gpu-tools xserver-xorg-video-intel-dbg xserver-xorg-video-radeon-dbg xserver-xorg-video-r128-dbg xserver-xorg-video-ati-dbg
```

note: using kernel 3.8.0-31-generic

I am not sure what did the trick but it worked, now I can see the `/sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch`.

Good luck,
Regards

Giri

Comment: I installed that packages but it didn't help :( Im really frustraded with that, there is no solution in sight. Well, I hope some future kernel will fix the problem.